# Pointer mechanism in Multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, double-pointer

I have some confusion in pointer mechanism in multi threading example below in marked lines that how a single pointer converting into double pointer

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *worker_thread(void *arg)
{
        pthread_exit((void*)911);  /// <-- HERE
}

int main()
{
        int i;
        pthread_t thread;
        pthread_create(&thread, NULL, worker_thread, NULL);
        pthread_join(thread, (void **)&i);  /// <-- HERE       
        printf("%d\n",i);                   /// will print out 911

}
```

Second if in place of a number below if I wanna return some integer value suppose I will take a variable 
`int i = 911` in `worker_thread` API and want to return `i` via `pthread_exit()` API how to do it and how to receive it via `pthread_join()` API and what is the mechanism of pointer conversion from single to double.

Comment: May I suggest that you don't try to learn complex pointers (including the rules about casting between them) and multithreading at the same time?

Comment: Have you tried to define `int i = 911` in `worker_thread` and call `pthread_exit((void*) i)`? You should get the same result; that is, `911` will be print out in `main`